# How to solve the Asymptotic Estimation

Tags: limits, asymptotics

How to prove that
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\ln\pi-\ln2}{2}x+o(x)(x\to0^+)$$

Comment: Do you know how to write that series in terms of the Riemann zeta function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}=(1-2^{1-x})\,\zeta(x)$$

When $x$ is small
$$2^{1-x}=e^{(1-x)\log(2)}=2-2 x \log (2)+O\left(x^2\right)$$ and
$$\zeta(x)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} x \log (2 \pi )+O\left(x^2\right)$$ Combine all of the above and simplify.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.And I want to know why $$\zeta(x)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x\ln2\pi+O(x^2)$$

Comment: I only know that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^x} = \frac{n^{1-x}}{1-x}+\alpha+O(\frac{1}{n^x})$$ The$\alpha$ is the constant

Comment: @yf1994. Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323916/what-is-the-power-series-expansion-for-riemann-zeta-at-0

Comment: Thank  you! And $$\zeta^{\prime}(0)$$

Comment: @yf1994. $\zeta'(0)=-\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi )$, $\zeta^{(n)}(0$ start to be complicated . Cheers :-)